# Slack API: channel_not_found error when using chat.postMessage

Tags: python-3.x, slack-api

I have written the code to post to a channel within the workspace on slack for any given channel (assuming it exists), but I keep getting the channel_not_found error on channels that

1.) I can verify that they do indeed exist

2.) The channels are not private as they have the # symbol in front of them and not a lock.

I have triple checked my slack app dashboard and it is installed on the workspace (verified with workspace admins also). I have stored both the OAuth Access Token (begins with xoxp) and the Bot User OAuth Access Token (begins with xoxb) as an environment variable on my machine. I have tried using both within the app and I get the same result with the following permissions/scopes: chat:write:bot, chat:write:user, and bot. I can send messages via webhooks, but am understanding that I need to create a webhook for each and every channel that the app may be posting to. This app needs to be versatile and able to direct message users depending on how they wish to be updated. Any help in finding why the channels cannot be found would greatly be appreciated. In the following code snippet, the post_channel() function is the test function that I am using and simple changing out channel names, etc.

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os

webhook_url = "a webhook url"


def post_message_channel(text, token, channel, is_name):

    """
    Creates an api call to post to a message to specific channel (private or
    public)and returns the JSON object that is returned by the slack api call.

    :param text: The message to post the slack channel.
    :param token: The slack app token to identify the sender.
    :param title: The title of the message being sent.
    :param channel: The channel to post the message to.
    :param is_name: If true, then the channel param holds a name, else it holds a channel id
    :return: The JSON object that the slack api responds with.
    """
    if is_name:
        formatted_channel = "#" + channel
    else:
        formatted_channel = channel
    slack_client = SlackClient(token)
    output_json = slack_client.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channels = formatted_channel,
        text = text,
        as_user = 1
    )
    return output_json


def post_channel():
    message = "This is a test for posting to a channel"
    my_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_USER_TOKEN"]
    print(post_message_channel(message, my_token, 'file_tracker_test', True))
```

Comment: Any update? Answer?